# how to calculate time based on particular column

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a column called "voltage" in "services" table, and the value will be vary from 0 to 100.

Based on the voltage value I have to display the uptime/downtim line chart. For example if the voltage is NIL/0 then the service is down. If the voltage > 0, then the service is up. What is the best logic to do this?

Comment: post your table structure ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 voltage,
 (CASE 
 WHEN NULLIF(voltage,'') IS NULL THEN 'Service is down'
 ELSE 'Service is up'
 END) as service
FROM services;
```

Or

```
SELECT 
 voltage,
 IF(voltage, 'Service is up', 'Service is down') as service
FROM services;
```

> [SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f696d4/2)

Comment: is their any way to calculate the time difference between the Up & down records, based on the timestamp column "created_at" in the table?

Comment: Could you explain it

Comment: I want to display the service up timings and down timings for given date range. For example total up time is sum of uptime time difference and down time is sum of total down  time based on the timestamp column "created_at".

Comment: Group by uptime and downtime and find the corresponding sums and find the difference.